# iMessage no longer able to reach a specific contact

Tags: iphone, messages

My friend H. is on assignment in Asia.  We iMessage a few times per week.

Last Thursday an iMessage I sent him got rejected:

[image]

This only happened when I iMessaged him, and he was still able to iMessage me.

We tried FaceTime and that didn't work either.

He fiddled with his settings and then when I tried to iMessage him I got the iPhone error message: "This person cannot be reached by iMessage at this time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was broken: the specific contact had changed his AppleID password and had not updated it on his iPhone.

The solution that worked for us:

1. He reset his AppleID (c.f.: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5624)
2. He updated the password at iPhone (iOS7) >> Settings >> Messages
3. He updated the password at iPhone >> Settings >> FaceTime
4. I reset my network settings: my iPhone (iOS7) >> Settings >> General >> Reset >> Reset Network Settings

He didn't have to reset his network settings, and neither of us powered our iPhones off/on.